# Calling super class constructor from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

```
class Top { 
    public Top(String s) { 
        System.out.print("B"); 
    }
}

public class Bottom2 extends Top {
    public Bottom2(String s) {  
        super();
        System.out.print("D"); 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Bottom2 as=new Bottom2("A");
        new Bottom2("C");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

I want to call the super class constructor. Why does this not compile ?

Comment: What makes you think it is not called? It should print `BDBD `

Comment: The constructor for Top takes a String so you should have written super(s);

Comment: I see, you are trying to say it doesn't even compile because you called `super()` incorrectly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `super()` implies that there is a default constructor in the base class. Your example does not show that so therefore the code does not compile.

So, in order for this to work properly simply add call in the subclass like this:

```
public Bottom2(String s) 
{   
    super(s); // call to superclass constructor with parameters.
    System.out.print("D"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `super()`, and not `super(s)`. When you have a parameterized constructor, you can no longer use the default no-arg constructor, that's why `super()` won't compile.

Comment: Maybe he is not aware, that when you define a constructor in a class, java no longer provides the default constructor and you have to do it yourself.

Comment: there is no default constructor- the explicit constructor has removed the implicit default constructor

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant, let me edit that. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't notice there was no no-arg constructor in the code, thanks for the hint. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your super class constructor contains 1 string parameter,
and you are not calling your super class with parameter

in the code 
super();

should be like this

super("any string");

Answer (score 0):

This program will give a compile time error.
It is  necessary to include a default constructor Top() in  the class Top

Answer (score 0):

First of all it will give compile time error (because if you are having argument-constructor in child class then you must have no -arg constructor in base class) and second that compiler will implicitly call no-arg constructor of base class(if no other call to super class constructor or child class constructor). so you should not write

```
super();
```

so you should call explicitly

```
super(s);
```